# Knotter Install on CygWin

Tags: python, gcc, installation

I have problem like this when installing knotter using cygwin. Please help me to solve the problem. I tried to install it as administrator, but it didn't help. I also tried some suggestions from this site. Please anyone can help me?

```
$ pip install knotter
Collecting knotter
  Using cached knotter-0.2.6.tar.gz
Collecting aiohttp>=0.16.5 (from knotter)
  Using cached aiohttp-2.2.3.tar.gz
Collecting pandas>=0.16.2 (from knotter)
  Using cached pandas-0.20.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found
    /bin/sh: svnversion: command not found
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl


1.13.1/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
          File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 674, in get_mathlib_info
            'pandas.tests.io.json',
        RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
        /bin/bash: gcc: command not found
        /bin/bash: gcc: command not found

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5ru8gzrw/pandas/

What should I do to solve this problem?
```

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~pkwong/ECE103_files/Resources/Compiler/C_GNU/GCC_Installation/How_to_Install_Cygwin+GCC.htm . You have to setup gcc in your environment.

Comment: Thank you. I've finished installing knotter, however I have other problem. Now I can't run the Knotter I've installed. These are the code displayed when running knotter using cygwin:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this link](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Epkwong/ECE103_files/Resources/Compiler/C_GNU/GCC_Installation/How_to_Install_Cygwin+GCC.htm).

You have to setup gcc in your environment. In the cygwin installation, select the following programs:

> gcc-core : C compiler subpackage
>
> gcc-g++ : C++ subpackage
>
> libgcc1 : C runtime library
>
> gdb : The GNU Debugger
>
> make : The GNU version of the 'make' utility

I hope it helps.